# JavaScript Abnormal Behaviour

Tags: c#, javascript

**Here is my code behind file:**

```
protected void btnCheckUserName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblShowUserName.Text = txtUserName.Text;
        }
```

**Here is my `.aspx` file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmName()
    {
        debugger;

        var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
        var flag = false;
        if (userName != "")
        {
            flag = window.confirm("You entered" + userName + ", Are you sure to continue?");
        }

        if (flag) {

            return true;

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

</script>
```

**Script is in my head section:**

**Here is the body:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="Name:" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCheckUserName" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="confirmName();" OnClick="btnCheckUserName_Click" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True"/></div>

        <asp:Label ID="lblShowUserName" runat="server"></asp:Label></form>
```

**Above is the Output:**

[image]
When i left the text box empty and click the button,why does my server side code execute?Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: So in your case, you want `OnClientClick="return confirmName();"`

Comment: @Andreas..Id is fine,when i left textbox empty and click the button,i don't know why my server side code executes,elsewise if i put some data in textbox,it works fine

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet...it is the thing i wants